# Python: How can I check the number of pending tasks in a multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, pool, multiprocess

I have a small pool of workers (4) and a very large list of tasks (5000~).  I'm using a pool and sending the tasks with map_async().  Because the task I'm running is fairly long, I'm forcing a chunksize of 1 so that one long process can't hold up some shorter ones.

What I'd like to do is periodically check how many tasks are left to be submitted.  I know at most 4 will be active, I'm concerned with how many are left to process.

I've googled around and I can't find anybody doing this.

Some simple code to help:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def mytask(num):
    print('Started task, sleeping %s' % num)
    time.sleep(num)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
jobs = pool.map_async(mytask, [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,5,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,4], chunksize=1)
pool.close()

while True:
    if not jobs.ready():
        print("We're not done yet, %s tasks to go!" % <somethingtogettasks>)
        jobs.wait(2)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I should note that I'm using python2.6 on a RHEL-6 system, however I'm open to examples on different versions/platforms.

Comment: static variable that gets decremented when task completes? (and incremented when task begins obviously).

Comment: Tasks don't "start" until the worker gets to them.  I suppose if I created a global that was the size of the tasks to be done, then decremented it each time a task started that might do it, but that's a bit awkward and requires some thread safety thought.

Comment: Changes to get the example code to compile and run: http://fpaste.org/p4Hb/ . Also: https://gist.github.com/902947

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `jobs._number_left` is what you want. `_` indicates that it is an internal value that may change at the whim of the developers, but it seems to be the only way to get that info.

Comment: Ah!  It wasn't in the API docs, and I had forgotten to do a dir() on jobs in ipython.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is there a good reason why _number_left is not in the API docs? Is it expected to become deprecated or have its name changed in the future?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the number of pending jobs by seeing `Pool._cache` attribute assuming that you are using `apply_async`. This is where `ApplyResult` is stored until they are available and equals to the number of `ApplyResult`s pending.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time


def job():
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,10))
    print("job finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(5)
    for _ in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(job)

    while pool._cache:
        print("number of jobs pending: ", len(pool._cache))
        time.sleep(2)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

No airtight way that I know of, but if you use the `Pool.imap_unordered()` function instead of map_async, you can intercept the elements that are processed.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

process_count = 4

def mytask(num):
    print('Started task, sleeping %s' % num)
    time.sleep(num)
    # Actually, you should return the job you've created here.
    return num

pool = multiprocess.Pool(process_count)
jobs  = []
items = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,5,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,4]
job_count = 0
for job in pool.imap_unordered(mytask, items):
    jobs.append(job)
    job_count += 1

    incomplete = len(items) - job_count
    unsubmitted = max(0, incomplete - process_count)

    print "Jobs incomplete: %s. Unsubmitted: %s" % incomplete, unsubmitted

pool.close()
```

I'm subtracting `process_count`, because you can pretty much assume that all processes will be processing with one of two exceptions: 1) if you use an iterator, there may not be further items left to consume and process, and 2) You may have fewer than 4 items left.  I didn't code in for the first exception.  But it should be pretty easy to do so if you need to.  Anyway, your example uses a list so you shouldn't have that problem.

Edit:  I also realized you're using a While loop, which makes it look like you're trying to update something periodically, say, every half second or something.  The code I gave as an example will not do it that way.  I'm not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't really explored the imap functions (docs were a bit... terse).  You are right though, I'd like to do some other things while the jobs are going, and periodically report on how many jobs are left.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirements: track progress, perform interim work based on the results, stop all processing cleanly at any arbitrary time. How I've dealt with it is to send tasks one at a time with `apply_async`. A heavily simplified version of what I do:

```
maxProcesses = 4
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
runlist = range(100000)
sendcounter = 0
donecounter = 0
while donecounter < len(runlist):
    if stopNowBooleanFunc():  # if for whatever reason I want to stop processing early
        if donecounter == sendcounter:  # wait til already sent tasks finish running
            break
    else:  # don't send new tasks if it's time to stop
        while sendcounter < len(runlist) and sendcounter - donecounter < maxProcesses:
            pool.apply_async(mytask, (runlist[sendcounter], q))
            sendcounter += 1

    while not q.empty():  # process completed results as they arrive
        aresult = q.get()
        processResults(aresult)
        donecounter += 1
```

Note that I use a `Queue` instead of `return`ing the results.