# How to measure progress in python mutiprocessing map_async?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I used to use this snippet to monitor the progress of of a multiprocess. Though, now q.qsize() stopped working and only returns zeros. Is there a replacement for what `q.qsize()` used to do formerly? Or is there a better way of doing that?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, cpu_count

def process(args):
    '''
    Pickleable function for (parallel) processing.
    Expects a dictionary with keys:
        Mandatory:
        - 'filename': 'path to file to be processed',
        ...
        Optional:
        - 'queue': instance of multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    '''
    filename = args['filename']
    mode = args['mode']

    if 'queue' in args.keys():
        q = args['queue']
        q.put('filename')
return do_something_with(filename)
...


pool = Pool(processes=nthreads)
m = Manager()
q = m.Queue()

# prepare args...

results = pool.map_async(process, args)

# monitor progress
while True:
    if results.ready():
        break
    else:
        size = q.qsize()
        self.progress = int(100 * (size / self.n_files))
        time.sleep(1)
self.progress = 100
```

Comment: Actually, I think this works. I had a bug in my code. And there was some code missing here that I added. But it is probably not the best way of doing this. The aim was to use process for serial and parallel cases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up your Pools and Queues. The multiprocessing Pool class handles the queuing logic for you but the Pool is not a Queue object, it's a Pool. So you're when you're checking your Queue size, there simply isn't anything there.

To directly answer your question though, your `q.qsize()` is always going to be 0 because you're not actually enqueuing anything to your Queue. Your queue is always empty. You need to `q.put()` something in your queue, if that is the behavior you are looking for.

Nothing that I know of will work exactly with your code as you have it right now with `pool.map_async`. I'm not sure how you want to approach it from here, but there are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807345/multiprocessing-pool-mapresult-number-left-not-giving-result-i-would-expect) and [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238691/counting-total-number-of-tasks-executed-in-a-multiprocessing-pool-during-executi?noredirect=1&lq=1) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542868/python-how-can-i-check-the-number-of-pending-tasks-in-a-multiprocessing-pool) about checking how many items are left in a Pool.

Comment: Oops, there was some code missing that I should have posted. Thanks for pointing that out.